# How to disable external sharing by default on SharePoint online site creation, but having it enabled by default on tenant level

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-sharing

I have a situation where I need to have external sharing enabled on SharePoint online tenant level but not on all the sites that get created. Currently all the sites that gets created has external sharing enabled by default. I only need certain site to have that ability. I cannot manually check all the newly created sites everyday.

Answer (score 0):

1.Sort by the 'Data Created' column (Newer to Older), then manually change the sharing settings.
[image: Date created]
[image: Only People]

2.You could use PowerShell to restrict sharing settings on individual SharePoint sites.

```
#Set Admin Center URL
$AdminCenterURL = "https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/operations"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
 
#Disable external sharing
Set-SPOSite $SiteURL -SharingCapability "Disabled"
```

Reference:[How to Disable External Sharing in SharePoint Online?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/05/how-to-disable-external-sharing-in-sharepoint-online.html)

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Is there any progress on this thread? Whether the answer helps you?